# change emacs shell background color only when connected to remote

Tags: emacs

Is there a way that I can make emacs change its color scheme automatically only when the shell is ssh'ing somewhere else? That is, keep a certain color for local shells vs a different color for remote shells?

Comment: You need to explain more.  Are you sshing into a remote machine, and then running emacs from there?  Or are you running e.g. eshell and sshing from that?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh.

Answer (score 2):

These days I've pushed `tramp-theme` to GNU ELPA, which should allow you to change buffer decoration depending on its `default-directory`. See the docstring of `tramp-theme-face-remapping-alist` for configuration.